# UIGestureRecognizer, making panned picture return to its original location

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to Objective-C. I'm making a simple app where I need a picture to move down to the bottom to the screen when pulled with finger. And then the picture should go back to its original location. How do I achieve this? This is what I have so far but I can't figure out the returning of the picture.

```
@implementation TestiAppViewController

-(IBAction)controlPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
if ((recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y < 320) && (recognizer.view.center.y +     translation.y > 100)) {
     recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x,recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
}

[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];

NSLog(@"Ended Center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(recognizer.view.center));

}
```

Comment: the image should go to original position after you end gesture or it should go to original position after it touches the end while moving???

Comment: The idea is that users drags a picture and when it reaches a certain point, a sound is released. When users releases picture, it should return to the original position. I'm a total newbie here :)

Answer (score 0):

I think add return statement. hope it would work

```
if ((recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y < 320) && (recognizer.view.center.y +     translation.y > 100)) {
     recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x,recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
return;
}
```